# Ansible Playbook: ERROR! 'command' is not a valid attribute for a Play

Tags: ansible

I'm just trying to write a basic playbook, and keep getting the error below.
Tried a tonne of things but still can't get it right. I know it must be a syntax thing but no idea where.

This is the code I have:

```
---
# This playbook runs a basic DF command.

- hosts: nagios
  #remote_user: root

  tasks:
  - name: find disk space available.
  command: df -hPT
```

This is the error I get:

```
> ERROR! 'command' is not a valid attribute for a Play
> 
> The error appears to have been in '/root/playbooks/df.yml': line 4,
> column 3, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact
> syntax problem.
> 
> The offending line appears to be:
> 
> 
> - hosts: nagios   
    ^ here
```

Ansible ver: 2.4.2.0

It's driving me insane. I've looked at some axamples from the Ansible docs, and it looks the same.
No idea...

Anyone know?

Comment: Are you passing in an inventory file with the -i flag or is the hosts block ([nagios]) in /etc/ansible/hosts?

Comment: The reason I ask is because the offending line appears to be 4, your hosts declaration. Looking at man page for ansible run https://linux.die.net/man/1/ansible-playbook the -i option is the path to hosts file, which defaults to /etc/ansible/hosts. Whatever inventory file you use needs to have the [nagios] block in it.

Comment: Hi Jesse, correct the ([nagios]) is located withing the hosts file at  /etc/ansible/hosts. Tried also the -i option with the path but still no go. Running a one liner on the prompt such as  ansible -m command -a 'df -hPT' nagios works fine, so i can rule out my entry in the hosts file as being the problem. thanks for the ideas btw...

Comment: Oh sorry also, command needs a tab before it? Looking at command documentation here: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/command_module.html

Comment: @Jesse Placed a tab before the "command" module now the error is : The offending line appears to be... and an arrow underneath the colon at the end of the command statement.

Comment: Sorry again, by tab I mean it should line up with "name" under tasks. See below

Comment: @Jesse Yep, that did it! Thanks for that! Do you know where I can find some doco about the formatting for Ansible playbooks? I've looked at the docs for playbooks on Ansible itself, but it doesn't explain this. Any good resources you recommend? and thanks again!

Comment: No worries. It's more yml/yaml understanding. Generally I'll just look at the module documentation https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules_by_category.html as they always have examples for each. Couple those with https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_intro.html and it should cover everything you'll need for Ansible Syntax.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The problem is that without the indentation of the command line, the command directive is part of the overall play, and not the task block.
i.e. **the command should be part of the task block**.

```
---
# This playbook runs a basic DF command.

- hosts: nagios
  #remote_user: root

  tasks:
  - name: find disk space available.
    command: df -hPT
```